# Instagram cancel button

Tags: ios, webview

I am using a `webView` to show Instagram login. However there is no cancel button. How do I add a cancel button? I tried to add a cancel button on top of the webView but it's not relative to the webView, in that if you were to drag down that window as if to refresh it,the cancel button will remain static. Is it possible to have it right next to the `Log in` button? If not is the `uINavigationBar` the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want from the cancel button is to close the `webView`, you can have the `webView` embedded in a `UIViewController` which is added to the `UINavigationController` stack. Then you will be able to add the Cancel Button as a `UIBarButtonItem` on the navigation bar.

For example:

Your home screen is `MainViewController` and you tap a button to show Instagram in webView. Then in your `MainViewController.m` (which is already the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController`) do this:

```
// Init your web view controller and push to UINavigationController stack to show it.
WebViewController *yourWebViewContainer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourWebViewContainer animated:YES];
```

Then in your `WebViewController.m` file, create the cancel button in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelTapped:)];
}
```

Comment: Hello Mach thank you. Would it be possible to if you could show it in swift as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with swift language, especially swift3.0, therefore I don't want to post any code from my guesses. But I believe it is not hard to convert it. You can try.

Comment: No worries. Glad that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the cancel button beside the Login button because it's in web view which contains html code, but you can add button on navigation bar using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelAction:)];          
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}

-(void)cancelAction:(UIButton *)sender{
   //do cancel action
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, the problem is that webView currently doesn't have a navigationBar, how can I add that dynamically?  or Should the original (the one calling webView) have one as well? Because it doesn't...